# What happens if you cast Shadowform the third time?

Tags: hearthstone

The Priest's *Shadowform* states that your Hero Spell does damage instead of healing. If you're already in Shadowform, it deals 3 damage instead of 2.

But what happens if you cast *Shadowform* again after this? Will your damage keep increasing by one or does it cap at 3 and any additional *Shadowform* casts are useless?

Comment: Based on card text I believe it would remain 3, but I have not been able to test that theory. Easiest way to test would be for you and a friend to duel using Priest vs Priest, each with 2 Thoughtsteal, Mindgames, Shadowform and a Lorewalker Cho

Comment: I stand corrected about the impossibility of being able to play more than 2 of the same card now...

Comment: In Arena, you can also play more than 2. That's not suitable for testing though for obvious reasons.

Comment: The question is valid enough, though the possibility is somewhat kinda slim I guess. But Im looking forward for someone to test this out.

Comment: Theoretically, you could get into a Shadowpriest mirror match. I assume Thoughtsteal is being played in that deck, maybe even Mind Vision...

Comment: The only reason why you would play three is if you wanted to use hero power again.

Comment: @ws04 very good point! It's not mana efficient, but if that's not relevant, the ability to do 3 additional damage is an important effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to HeartPwn, it will stay at 3 damage. http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/421-shadowform